# Unable to use networking (apt-get) in Docker 12.04 under Windows

Tags: networking, ubuntu, docker, ubuntu-12.04, docker-for-windows

I must create a Docker container for Ubuntu 12.04.
I am setting up the container into a Windows 10 VM.
To get build tools, I need to get `apt-get install` to work, but it can't reach its sources.

I am unable to get any networking on the 12.04. ping not installed, nor any networking tools (`iputils`). `apt-get update` which is what I really need, not working.
I have tried a more recent Ubuntu version, and that works.

This works:

```
docker run -it --network bridge ubuntu:latest bash
root@3502f6313799:/# apt-get update
...
Fetched 20.4 MB in 47s (438 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

This doesn't work:

```
docker run -it --network bridge ubuntu:12.04 bash
root@32a12a2483a6:/# apt-get update
...
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
...
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
...
```

I am just starting to use Docker, so far my searches found nothing that can help.

Please help me get any networking tools, any way to get the debians I need into the image, or give me ideas on troubleshooting.

Comment: Support for Ubuntu 12.04 ended many years ago. As such, that it doesn't support newer hardware, including virtualized devices, is entirely expected. And, of course, no unsupported OS should be used online even in a VM, you're endangering your whole network and likely beyond.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Ubuntu 12.04 can be installed in a VM, with any networking tools desired, and its access can be limited to apt-get if desired. You maybe missed the part where it is a Docker image.

Comment: No, I didn't miss that part :)

Comment: Since I am building a toolchain for an embedded system that uses 12.04, I need to set up the 12.04 image in Docker. Whether through apt-get - which is not endangering the host or its network - or through other means if networking is not possible.  I just need help to get me started since I am not used to have such a bare bone system.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Ubuntu 12.04 Precise repositories have moved. I had to modify the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to use `../old-releases/..` instead of `../archive/..` and all other prefixes.

And, since neither `nano` nor `vi` were available, I had to edit the file outside, and copy it into the container.

EDIT: You can do this in a Dockerfile as follows -

```
FROM ubuntu:12.04   
RUN sed -i s/archive/old-releases/g etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ...
```